# Proof of a property of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Is this statement true: $$HH^\dagger = H^\dagger H \implies H = H^\dagger$$

NOTE: $H^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of $H$

If so, can somebody provide a proof?

Comment: What is $H^\dagger$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Conjugate transpose, especially in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Your *implicans* is socalled *normality* of an operator and your *implicandum* is socalled *self-adjointness*. For example unitary operators are normal but not self-adjoint, hence your statement is in general false.

Comment: @Peter Wildermann Yeah, you're right. Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true: $(-i)\cdot i = i\cdot (-i)$ but $i\ne -i$.

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted this. This is the easiest counterexample.

Comment: But are $1$ and $-1$ conjugate transposes?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Thnx @ChristianF

Answer (score 1):

No this is not the case.

A matrix with this property (that it commutes with its conjugate transpose) is said to be [*Normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

As an example

$$H =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0  \end{array}\right)$$

Then clearly $H \neq H^\dagger$, but you can show $ H H^\dagger = H^\dagger H = I$, the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a diagonal matrix, then $H.H^\dagger=H^\dagger.H$, but you will only have $H=H^\dagger$ if all entries are real.